# style change remain on select after focus is lost?

Tags: css, highlight

I have a page with multiple select drop downs and was wondering if there is some simple way that once an element is selected and loses focus it retains a style change - so that the user has a visual clue as to which elements he has selected i.e. I might have a small green border around each select that is something other than the default "-select-" value. I'm not a coder and there are about 240 selects on it, along with other code which I'm not comfortable monkeying with.

I can highlight the row and select using pseudo classes but can't figure a simple way to retain a visual cue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLcpX.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this can't be done with pure CSS.

But you can use JavaScript like this to achieve the same effect:

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var element = event.target;
    if(element.tagName == 'SELECT'){
        element.style.border = "1px solid green";
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xm1txLws/

**UPDATE**

To check if the default option is selected again, you need to perform an additional check (if no value tag is given for the selected option the value becomes the containing text):

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(event){
    var element = event.target;
    if(element.tagName == 'SELECT'){
        element.style.border = "1px solid green";
        if(element.value == '-select-'){
            element.style.border = "none";
        }
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xm1txLws/3/

Comment: A follow up question. Is it possible to modify this so that if the option text is "-select-" it doesn't show this? Because someone can pick anything an set it back to select and the green box gives it the illusion it is valid. Something like if(element.tagName == 'SELECT') AND option.text NOT EQ "-select-"